# Where do these boot log entries come from and who creates them?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-kernel, syslog, rsyslog

I'm wondering what kind of code writes these first two lines into `/var/log/syslog` while booting my machine:

```
Aug  4 10:13:48 HOSTNAME kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Aug  4 10:13:48 HOSTNAME rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="2103" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug  4 10:13:48 HOSTNAME kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Aug  4 10:13:48 HOSTNAME kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
```

1. The first line says `kernel:` but nowhere in kernel sources I can find the strings, so it can't be the kernel. It cannot be grub neither, since I didn't find it in their sources. Where does it come from then?
2. The second line is suspicious too. It can't be a regular thread/process, since it's much too early in boot process, though it says rsyslogd. It cannot be found in kernel sources nor grub nor in rsyslog sources. Where does it come from then?

Comment: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imklog.html. I would assume then that this a module loaded by the Kernel to do what the documentation page describes.

Comment: But there's no such code, I `grep`ed the sources.

Comment: Yes there is. You just have to look at the _correct_ version of the source code. `./plugins/imklog/linux.c:               imklogLogIntMsg(LOG_INFO, "imklog %s, log source = ksyslog "`   (as of version 5.8.11 of rsyslogd).

Comment: You are right, indeed. Now I wonder why there is a `kernel:` in front and thus where the kernel calls this function. Or does grub call it? Don't really get the flow there but it has to be grub I guess because the kernel has probably not been initialized at that moment.